# possible lossy conversion from int to short

Tags: java, arrays, int, short

I have defined array gx, array arr to be short type. but why the operation at left may end up with int type and I must cast it into short? the compiler error is possible lossy conversion from int to short.

this is my code.

```
public PixImage sobelEdges() {

short gy=0;
for(int x=1;x<width-1;x++){
    for(int y=1;y<height-1;y++){
       // if(x=){
            for(int z=0;z<3;z++){
            gx[x][y][z]=arr[x-1][y-1][z]-arr[x+1][y-1][z]+2*arr[x-1][y][z]-2*arr[x+1][y][z]+arr[x-1][y+1][z]-arr[x+1][y+1][z];

            }
       // }    
    }     
}   
return this;
// Don't forget to use the method mag2gray() above to convert energies to
// pixel intensities.
```

}

Is that because the so called unbox? so that means every time I made a operation I need to cast?

Comment: `int` is bigger than `short`.  Loss of bits may occur.

Comment: The compiler is probably noticing that you're multiplying `short` values together and storing the result into a `short`.  There is a chance that the result of the multiplication will be larger than a `short`.  This has nothing to do with Boxing/Unboxing.  That refers to implicit conversion from `int` to `Integer`, for example.

Comment: Try casting your 2's to shorts.  (short)2*arr...

Comment: thnx! a lot need to learn

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not unboxing; it's "binary numeric promotion".  [Section 5.6.2 of the JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) states:

> When an operator applies binary numeric promotion to a pair of operands, each of which must denote a value that is convertible to a numeric type, the following rules apply, in order:
>
> 1. If any operand is of a reference type, it is subjected to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8).
> 2. Widening primitive conversion (§5.1.2) is applied to convert either or both operands as specified by the following rules:
>
>    - If either operand is of type double, the other is converted to double.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type float, the other is converted to float.
>    - Otherwise, if either operand is of type long, the other is converted to long.
>    - **Otherwise, both operands are converted to type int**.

and

> Binary numeric promotion is performed on the operands of certain operators:
>
> - The multiplicative operators *, /, and % (§15.17)
> - The addition and subtraction operators for numeric types + and - (§15.18.2)
> - The numerical comparison operators <, <=, >, and >= (§15.20.1)
> - The numerical equality operators == and != (§15.21.1)
> - The integer bitwise operators &, ^, and | (§15.22.1)
> - In certain cases, the conditional operator ? : (§15.25)

(emphasis mine)

When those values are added/multiplied, they are promoted to `int` before the math is done.  At the end, you can cast back to `short` before assigning back to the array.

```
gx[x][y][z] = (short) (arr[x-1][y-1][z]-arr[x+1][y-1][z]+2*arr[x-1][y][z]
    -2*arr[x+1][y][z]+arr[x-1][y+1][z]-arr[x+1][y+1][z]);
```

You will need to cast it back every time you operate with primitive data types that are smaller than `int`, such as in your `short` example.